# Detecting Width vs detecting browser

Tags: html, css, browser, device

I have a friend who does web design and he started talking about how he usually does his detection for what is being used.

He usually does a detection on how much available height and width he has and adjust everything from that. So basically you can view something as an "iPod" view on a computer if you adjust the width close enough it will look like it.

So my point is what is better and why? Pro and Cons?

Would it be better to adjust everything from width or would it be to detect the browser being used and adjust from there. Such as a mobile phone browser was detected and etc.

What do you prefer?

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with that [Responsive Web Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) since you can cover more platforms without special treatment.

The only reason I'd check for the browser/OS is if I wanted to keep the look and feel of native apps - that is when I explicitly want to adhere to the specific [iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) or [Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html) (etc.) UI guidelines. But that would be more work as you'd had to implement your layout for each platform instead of for *all at once*.

Comment: +1 for the look & feel issue

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go with detecting width and height.

Even if you detect a smartphone browser, there can be many different screen sizes and different resolution. Not mentioning tablets. Not mentioning desktop users with different screen sizes. Not mentioning desktop users resizing their window.

In addition, browser detection is not always reliable.

I recommend learning more about **responsive web design** (e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) or [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)).

It's the same principle as when you need to detect browser features (JS, CSS) -- libraries like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) do not detect the browser from the reported user agent but detect the actual features it implements. Features may change in time and you would constantly need to update your code. Analogously, mobile browsers may have some resolution nowadays and a completely different one in the future.